# Creating a user defined function

Tags: php

I'm supposed to create a function that uses 2 arguments. Both of the arguments are strings. One of the arguments is text and the other argument is a letter, either `A` or `B`. If it's `A`, I need to change the case using the built in PHP function of the text to upper case. If it's `B`, I need to change the case using the built in PHP function of the text to lower case.

I know I have to use an elseif statement.

```
function paint($case, $str)
{
  if $case = A echo $sentence ($str);
  else echo upper($str);
}

$sentence = "Placeholder text here.";
paint("a", $sentence);
paint("b", $sentence);
```

Comment: any example code? What did you try?

Comment: Sure, here is something I tried to do. 

`<?php

function paint($case, $str){
 if $case = A
  echo $sentence ($str);
 else echo upper ($str);
}
$sentence = "Placeholder text here.";
paint ("a", $sentence);
paint ("b", $sentence);`

Comment: The first thing is to write a clear function signature, something like `function change_case($text, $caseType)`

Comment: @Aestrial, edit your question instead of posting the code in comments

Comment: Hi. You're at highschool, that's great. SO can be a great place, if you respect some principles. IMHO, the first one to respect is: there should be a sentence with a question mark. The second: provide the code, as ugly as it may be. Make sure to reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: Third: use the [edit] feature to change the text of your question.

Comment: You should learn the basic syntax of PHP, because this code is just a big syntax error and doesn't make any sense

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `switch..case` statement

```
function paint($case, $str)
{
  switch (strtolower($case))
  {
    case 'a': $str = strtoupper($str);
    break;

    case 'b': $str = strtolower($str);
    break;
  }
  echo $str;
}

$sentence = "Placeholder text here.";
paint("a", $sentence);        // PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE.
paint("b", $sentence);        // placeholder text here.
paint("nonsense", $sentence); // Placeholder text here.
```

Or if you want to throw an exeption when neither "a" nor "b" was given, change the `switch` block to:

```
switch (strtolower($case))
{
  case 'a': $str = strtoupper($str);
  break;

  case 'b': $str = strtolower($str);
  break;

  default :
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('First argument of function "' . __FUNCTION__ . '" is expected to be a string either "a" or "b".');
}
```

The `switch`..`case` construct is an alternative form of multiple `if`..`elseif`..`else` statements, except that the condition works as an entry point. If you do not use explicit `break` statements, the execution will fall-through to the next case. `default` is the entry point if no other cases are matching.

Comment: This definitely helps. I appreciate it a ton, it helps to have something to go off of. So the output of the code should look like this: `a: PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE.
b: placeholder text here". How would I move forward in adding "a" and "b" to the output?